# Setting the font in XSL-FO with fop

Tags: fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have in the `.fonts/Dinarra/` folder the files `Dinarra LT Std-Roman.otf` and `Dinarra LT Std-Italic.otf`.

The font configuration in `fop.xconf` is as follow:

```
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
  ...
  <fonts>
    ...
    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="'~/.fonts/Dinarra/DinarraLTStd-Roman.otf'" embedding-mode="subset">
      <font-triplet name="'Dinarra LT Std'" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    </font>

    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="'~/.fonts/Dinarra/DinarraLTStd-Roman.otf'" embedding-mode="subset">
      <font-triplet name="'Dinarra LT Std'" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    </font>

    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="'~/.fonts/Dinarra/DinarraLTStd-Italic.otf'" embedding-mode="subset">
      <font-triplet name="'Dinarra LT Std'" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
    </font>

    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="'~/.fonts/Dinarra/DinarraLTStd-Italic.otf'" embedding-mode="subset">
      <font-triplet name="'Dinarra LT Std'" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
    </font>

    <auto-detect/>
  </fonts>
</renderer>
```

I have registered the fonts in fop with `fop -c ~/.fop/fop.xconf`.

Now I have the following XSL-FO code in the file `test.fob`:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="first-page-before">
  <fo:block font-family="'Dinarra LT Std'" font-size="28pt"
      font-style="normal" font-variant="small-caps">
    <fo:block>S.E. Reverendo</fo:block>
    <fo:block>Gabriele Asperso</fo:block>
  </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

Compiled with `fop -c ~/.fop/fop.xconf -r test.fob test.pdf`, with the following output:

```
rev@asp-erso ~/repos/f5qg16 $ fop -c ~/.fop/fop.xconf -r test.fob test.pdf
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: No java runtime was found
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: No java runtime was found
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: No JAVA_CMD set for run_java, falling back to JAVA_CMD = java
[INFO] FopConfParser - Default page-height set to: 11.00in
[INFO] FopConfParser - Default page-width set to: 8.50in
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Border and padding for fo:region-before "first-page-before" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position 23:68)
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Border and padding for fo:region-after "first-page-after" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position 25:62)
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #1.
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #2.
```

The problem is that the blocks are rendered with italic fonts, not normal, not small-caps.

If I delete the file `Dinarra LT Std-Italic.otf` from the font folder then the blocks are rendered as expected (but not small-caps), but this way I can't have italic any more.

My questions are:

1. How can I set the fonts properly in the XSL-FO declaration, so that I can use normal style without deleting the italic file?
2. How can I set the font so that I can obtain the small-caps variant?

---

### Part 2: Some experiments

I have double checked that there is not the word "italic" anywhere in
the test document before the declaration of the `static-content`;

I have triple checked the exacteness of the font file paths in the
file `~/.fop/fop.xconf`;

I have deleted the file `~/.fop/fop-fonts.cache` and modified the file
`~/.fop/fop.xconf` this way:

```
<!-- ### deleted some 'font' element -->
<font kerning="yes"
      embed-url="'~/.fonts/Dinarra/DinarraLTStd-Roman.otf'"
      embedding-mode="subset">
  <font-triplet name="'Dinarra LT Std'"
                style="normal"
                weight="normal"/>
</font>

<font kerning="yes"
      embed-url="'~/.fonts/Dinarra/DinarraLTStd-Italic.otf'"
      embedding-mode="subset">
  <font-triplet name="'Dinarra LT Std'"
                style="italic"
                weight="normal"/>
</font>

<!-- ### commented-out auto-detect-->
<!-- <auto-detect/> -->
```

I have compiled the test document re-registering the font with

```
fop -c ~/.fop/fop.xconf -r test.fob test.pdf
```

the output is:

```
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: No java runtime was found
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: No java runtime was found
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: No JAVA_CMD set for run_java, falling back to JAVA_CMD = java
[INFO] FopConfParser - Default page-height set to: 11.00in
[INFO] FopConfParser - Default page-width set to: 8.50in
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Border and padding for fo:region-before "first-page-before" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position 23:68)
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Border and padding for fo:region-after "first-page-after" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position 25:62)
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Font "Dinarra LT Std,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #1.
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #2.
```

So (line 8) fop doesn't fint the font (!).

Then I have newly deleted the file `~/.fop/fop-fonts.cache` and
re-enabled the `auto-detect` directive, and finally re-compiled the
test file. The output is 23,175 lines long, none of which contains the
word 'Dinarra', nor the word 'otf'.

But the content of the `fo:static-content` element is still composed
with italic.

---

I don't know what to think more.

Comment: The configuration seems indeed correct, is it possible that there is a `font-style="italic"` in an ancestor element (`fo:page-sequence` or `fo:root`)?

Comment: @lfurini I have added part two of the question. I hope it can give you more elements useful to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the blocks are rendered with italic fonts, not normal

This could be a simple case of copy-and-paste error or typo in the font registration.

Check for warnings or errors in the output notifying you of font substitutions; if there is none, double-check that you associated the italic font file with the italic style, and the normal font file with the normal style.

> not small-caps

This problem is both simpler and more serious: unfortunately FOP [does not support `font-variant` yet](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-font-variant).

Comment: I've added my font configuration, a bulk configuration as indicated in the [fop website](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#bulk).

If I decide to add font configuration, have I to add a line for every font-weight, even if the font-file is the same? Something like

    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/System/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
        <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="100"/>
        <font-triplet name="Arial" style="bold" weight="400"/>
    </font>

Comment: @ReverendoAsperso You can have many `font-triplet`s inside each `font` element, but you don't need to add one for all the possible weights: if a specific (name, style, weight) is not explicitly mapped, FOP will use the same font as the most similar configured triplet (for example, using the normal font file for the bold text too).